# Getting error during installing (yum install php54w-devel` at CentOS 5.9)

Tags: php, centos

During installing of `yum install php54w-devel` at CentOS 5.9.

I got an error:

> Missing Dependency: libedit.so.0 is needed by package
>   php54w-devel-5.4.45-2.w5.i386 (webtatic-el5)

How can I fix it?

Comment: libedit is not available in the base repo in Centos5, turn on [EPEL](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL). Also get off of Centos5, support ends in March.

Comment: Thanks ! Is It possible for CentOS 5 to have php ver.5.4+ ?